# java get property only exist in child class

Tags: java

```
class Parent {

}

class Child extends parent {

 String something;
//get and set
}


Parent parent = getChildObject();
```

//without casing `getChildObject()` to `Child` object. i cannot do   `child.getSomething();` Can i do something like `parent.getProperty("something");` to get the value?

Comment: What would you expect it to do if it turned out that `parent` wasn't an instance of `Child`?

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do this is:

```
if (parent instanceof Child) {
    String something = ((Child) parent).getSomething();
}
```

You can also do this by using [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/), but that is a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use could always use reflection. But it will be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, what you are trying to do is not a good idea and you should try to avoid it.  If there is no way around it then the answer provided by nfechner is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question. But anyway...this is usually done by declaring an *abstract* method in the superclass and having the subclass(es) provide their own implementation. For instance,

```
abstract class Foo{
    abstract String getString();
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    @Override
    String getString(){
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

It's important to note that this will require the superclass to be *abstract*.